# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod works ok in Powershell V3 but fails in V4

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a simple PowerShell script that works OK in PowerShell V3.0 but fails in V4.0. Here is the script:

```
$url = "https://www.oanda.com/rates/api/v1/rates/USD.csv?quote=CNY&quote=EUR&quote=GBP&quote=KRW&fields=averages&api_key=Yv0C4DZ2rFOybbnGwzj7niFh"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -OutFile "C:\output.csv"
```

When I first ran it at V4.0 it generated an error like below

> Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed:  could not
>   establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I searched similar claims from various sites and I tried a solution others said work:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

It did not work for me.

Comment: Since it's a different powershell version, can I assume that this is a different machine, or did you upgrade powershell on the same machine?

Comment: It is a different machine with powershell v4.

Comment: If you visit https://www.oanda.com/rates/api/v1/ in a browser, do you have any certificate errors? By the way you might want to edit out your API key and request a new one.

Comment: No, I ran the browser and it never shows any problem. I think it is to do with powershell v4. By the way, when I add the following line code above existing codeit shows a different error message. The line code is:    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}. The new error message shows: Invoke-RestMethod: The underlying connection was closed; An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Comment: I ran your sample code in powershell v4 and it worked without any issue. Have you tried it on any other v4 machines? At this point I think you might want to run a packet capture.

Comment: I tried another machine with powershell v4 and it DID work. Apparently it is a computer specific problem. Thank you very much.